# Pass ls out to sql in

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm making a script to load a backup in SQL but I can not pass the result of ls to SQL. This is not working:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/mysql ges -h localhost -u root -p****** << ls -t /backup/mysqldump_ges* | head -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load a backup into MySQL you have to use the following format:

```
mysql -uroot -p***** < backup.sql
```

and the backup must be a SQL file e.g. generated by a mysqldump.

From your question it looks like you want to import to MySQL the first file of the directory. In this case the command is

```
mysql -uroot -p***** < $(ls | head -n 1)
```